# Layer added but not displayed until i turn off then on in LayerSwitcher

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I'm using OpenLayers to add a WFS layer. It works fine when i add it to init() function. But when i add the code to a function that is called by a button, layer gets added, but it does not display. It only displays if i uncheck and recheck the layer in the LayerSwitcher control.

I tried different things like the display and drawFeature funtions but they didn't work for me. IE:

```
wfs.display(true);
```

**What can i do to Add AND DISPLAY my wfs layer?**

here is my test code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" /> 
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/OpenLayers/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <title>WFS: GetFeature Example (GeoServer)</title> 
    <script src="../js/OpenLayers/lib/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map, layer, select, hover, control;
        OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "../secure/proxy/proxy.ashx?url=";
        var lon = 0;
        var lat = 0;
        var zoom = 0;
        function AddResultsLayer() {

            var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                    featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                    featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
                }),
                styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                    strokeColor: "#333333"
                })
            })
            map.addLayer(wfs);
        }

        function init() {

            map = new OpenLayers.Map({
                div: "map",
                center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
                minResolution: "auto",
                minExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1, -1, 1, 1),
                maxResolution: "auto",
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -90, 180, 90)
            });

            var basemap = 
                new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "Natural Earth",
                    "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms",
                    { layers: "topp:naturalearth" }
                )


            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

            map.addLayer(basemap);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);

        }
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body onload="init()"> 
<h1 id="title">WFS Test</h1> 

<div id="tags"> 
WFS, GetFeature
</div> 

<p id="shortdesc"> 
    Shows how to use the GetFeature control to select features from a WMS layer.
</p> 

<div id="map" class="smallmap"></div> 

<div id="docs"> 
   <input id="cmdAddLayer" type="button" value="button" onclick="AddResultsLayer(); return false;" />
</div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's working now. I guess you need to call the refresh operation like so:

```
function AddResultsLayer() {

    var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "tasmania_roads",
            featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
        }),
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            strokeWidth: 3,
            strokeColor: "#333333"
        })
    })
    map.addLayer(wfs);
    wfs.refresh();

}
```

Key line being:

```
wfs.refresh();
```